# Populate JavaFX tableview from several database tables

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm new in JavaFX platform, but feeling goog myself in Java. how I can populate JavaFX TableView from several tables in DB? i found numerous examples with populating from one simple table, but nothig about 2 or 3 tables.

Comment: When you say populate from 2 or 3 tables, do the (let's assume 2) 2 tables together form rows (each providing different columns), or do they result in different rows with similar data / fields ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new class containing the id's of both tables. And then, using that newly created class, you can modify your tableColumns' cellValueFactories

```
tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<NewlyCreatedClass, Integer>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<NewlyCreatedClass, Integer> param) {
        String str=processTheValueYouWant(param.getValue());
        return new SimpleStringProperty(str);
    }
});
```